# Ideas on machine learning algorithms to paint on a canvas

Tags: machine-learning

I am completely new to machine learning.
I explain the problem with an example.

I have a two dimensional white canvas.
The shape of the canvas is an arbitrary closed curve.
I have a brush, it is represented as a circle having a radius small enough to reach all corners of the canvas.
I have also blue paint.

I would like use a machine learning algorithm to create a trajectory of the brush in order to paint all the canvas in blue.
I attach a sketch of the problem.
[image]

Q1) Is there any machine learning algorithm available for such kind of problems?
Q2) If an algorithm does not exist, then may you indicate any reference I could study (book, paper, website) to learn how to write such an algorithm, please?

Any other suggestion of where to focus my studies for this problem is appreciated.

In my problem I have a "painter" acting as a reference motion. I would like my machine learning to mimic the painter.

Comment: There are plenty of ways machine learning *could* be used to solve this problem, but it's not needed at all. For example, even the simplest random walk is guaranteed to fill the canvas eventually. If you want something more efficient, hand-code some instructions to sweep back and forth like a robotic vacuum cleaner (as in your example). You could even search for an optimal (e.g. shortest) path that fills the canvas. This would be an optimization problem, and still requires no machine learning. Can you say more about your motivation? Why think about machine learning here?

Comment: I have voted to close this question. As user20160 says, it is unclear what the machine learning problem is.

Comment: *" I have a "painter" acting as a reference motion. I would like my machine learning to mimic the painter."* Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I want to submit to the machine motion clips on how the painter paint on some canvasses, then I want my machine to paint on any given canvas.

Comment: @Makkun what is the machine supposed to learn from the painter that you can't program right away with some straightforward algorithm?

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus I am aware that it is possible to use a straightforward algorithm to solve the problem. I am just wandering whether it is possible to solve the problem using machine learning, and if possible which algorithm to use, or where to look for ideas.

Comment: @Makkun the problem with this question is that there is nothing to learn. Or at least it is unclear what there is to learn. You make a description 'I want a machine to learn how to paint by watching videos' but that is very broad. What sort of sensors and motors is the robot gonna have to be able to match the experiences from the video with his own reality? How are you gonna give the robot feedback? ...

Comment: ... it is an interesting idea maybe. If you are a lazy programmer that doesn't want to program an algorithm to have the robot clean then you could have the robot discover an algorithm by itselve. But, the connection still feels flimsy. How are we supposed to answer the question with so little information about the robot and it's purpose in life?

Comment: The answer to Q1 is. Yes, there are algorithms. ... But they are complex algorithms. E.g. to have a computer learn play chess or GO, a large team of computer scientists had to work on it. This makes sense if you want to beat the world's best chess player or GO player, but you are trying to paint a canvas completely blue, a bit of an overkill to use machine learning for this. This makes it unclear what your question is really about. It's a bit like the saying 'If all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail', and your question is like asking what hammer you need for painting a canvas.

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus,  What if I acquire the trajectories of the painter when moving on the canvasses. Can the trajectories be fed-in to the robot to teach the robot how to paint? Would this case also require complex machine learning algorithm?.

Comment: @Makkun it would help if you would explain more about the underlying problem and motivation behind this question. That would clarify what you are trying to get with this example. Or are you truly trying to have a robot paint a canvas blue by learning from video's of painters?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you have fallen into a common trap, and it is worth addressing early in your machine learning journey, even if this is more like an extended comment than an answer.

Machine learning is interesting, machine learning can solve difficult problems, and machine learning can get you a job that pays a lot of money.

Machine learning is not everything, and machine learning is not synonymous with writing Python code that does math or works with data.

If you just want to paint the shape blue, I do not see this as a machine learning problem. The comment by User20160 gets into some ways to solve the problem.

As the saying goes, to the carpenter who only has a hammer, everything looks like a nail, yet the good carpenter will also have a saw. Some aspects of carpentry just are not tasks for a hammer.

Machine learning is your hammer, but you should solve this with a saw (better yet, a paintbrush).